# Linkedin Plugin for Wordpress. Customizing dimensions of the block

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

Is there a way to customize the dimensions of the LinkedIn plugin displayed on a wordpress site, through the javascript code I got on the developers page?

Here are the various plugins they offer: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins#

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might help to reference the specific plugin you plan to use in case its available styles are different from the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can change dimensions with data-width and data-height, for example LinkedIn generates the below code for a generic company profile plugin:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1337" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
```

You can add data-width and data-height to change dimensions like this:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1337" data-format="inline" data-related="false" data-width="400" data-height="250"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why it doesn't change anything... Any other suggestion?

Comment: CSS and reference the container class/ID I guess